# How is my Python code to construct node neighbors from edge list going so wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, tree

I am working with trees and I've written some simple code to convert a list of edges, expressed as node number pairs, to a neighbors array where with i-th element is supposed to be a list of node i's neighboring nodes.  The code is:

```
def calculateNeighbors( n, edges ):
    neighbors = [[]] * n
    for edge in edges:
        v1 = edge[ 0 ]
        v2 = edge[ 1 ]
        neighbors[ v1 ].append( v2 )
        neighbors[ v2 ].append( v1 )
    return neighbors
```

When I run this for `n`=`4` and `edges`=`[[1,0],[1,2],[1,3]]`, I get the following result:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1], [0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1], [0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1], [0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1]]
```

which looks like four copies of the edge list.  Can someone *please* point out where I'm going wrong?   I expected the result to be something like
`[[1],[0,2,3],[1],[1]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the problem.   The way I'm initializing "neighbors", the four sublists are the same object.  Betting to say

```
neighbors = [ [] for i in range( n ) ]
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer if it solved the problem.